# Equivariance in definition of symmetric operads

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, category-theory, higher-category-theory, operads

I know that there are some questions regarding symmetric operads, but I feel like asking yet another question.

Consider the operad $A$ with $A(n)=k[S_n]$. Let us denote the simple transpositions in $S_n$ by $s_1^{(n)},\dotsc,s_{n-1}^{(n)}$. If I have understood things correctly, algebras over this operad should be associative $k$-algebras.

Now, let's verify that there is a single multiplication indeed. Let $\mu = 1e \in A(2)$ be a fixed binary multiplication ($e$ is the empty word) and $\mu s$ be the multiplication with reversed arguments.

Now, I want to show that $\mu(\mu\otimes 1)$ and $\mu(1\otimes\mu)$ are the same. Let $M$ be an $A$-algebra and $x, y, z\in M$. Let $\theta_1=\mu$ and $\theta_2=1$.

Then

$$\begin{aligned} &\phantom{{}={}}\mu(1\otimes \mu) (x\otimes y\otimes z)\\
&= \mu(\theta_2\otimes \theta_1) (x\otimes y\otimes z)\\
&= \mu(\theta_{s^{(2)}(1)} \theta_{s^{(2)}(2)}) (x\otimes y\otimes z)\\
&= \mu s (\theta_1, \theta_2) s^{(3)}_1 s^{(3)}_2 (x\otimes y\otimes z)\\
&= \mu s (\mu\otimes 1)(z\otimes y\otimes x)\end{aligned}$$

which doesn't help at all.

So, how do I show that multiplication in an $A$-algebra needs to be associative?

*Edit:* To make it a little bit more clear: From the definition, I know that $S_3$ acts freely on $A(3)$. Thus, I know that $\mu(\mu\otimes 1)$ can be written as a linear combination

$$\mu(\mu\otimes 1) = \sum_{\sigma\in S_n} \lambda_\sigma \mu(1\otimes\mu)\sigma$$

for $\lambda_\sigma\in k$. If I am working with set-valued operads, I even have $\mu(\mu, 1) = \mu(1,\mu)\sigma$ for some $\sigma\in S_3$. However, how do I know that actually $\mu(\mu\otimes 1) = \mu(1\otimes \mu)$ from that?

Comment: The key point that you seem to be missing is that composition in any algebra is the same as composition in $A(n)$, so if $1_n$ is the identity in $S_n$, then $1_2\circ (1_2, 1_1) = 1_3 = 1_2\circ (1_1,1_2)$, and $1_2$ should be the operation corresponding to $\mu$ under the algebra map (this is because the composition in $A(n)$ is disjoint union of permutations with blocks reordered according to the operation which is being applied).

Comment: @jgon Yes, it seems I have missed that both $1_2(1_2\otimes 1_1)$ and $1_2(1_1\otimes 1_2)$ must be $1_3$.